# Fastes PHP Multidimensional Array matching

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

If I have two arrays, one which is a one dimensional array, the second is a undefined depth Multidimensional Array. 
I would like to execute a function on the fields from both if the key matches and its not an iterable instance.

The first array is something like this

```
$array = array(
"st" => "1",
"gr" => "2",
```

);

And the second...

```
$array = array(
"foo" => "bar",
"bar" => array(
    "st" => "fr",
    "gr" => "et",
),
```

);

What is the fastest method to achieve this?
what i have though about.

```
    foreach (array as key => value) {
        recursiveLoop($multidemsnionalArray, $key, $value)
    }

function recursiveLoop($multidemsnionalArray, $key, $value){
    foreach ($multidemsnionalArrayas as $key2 => $value2) {
        if (is_array($value2) or ($value2 instanceof Traversable)){
                recursiveLoop($value2, $key, $value);
        }
        else{
            //do the Foo
        }
    }
}
```

This is very ineffcient, the time will be according to the length of the first array times the length of the second.
would i best do this or try something else?

Comment: If the second array's structure is so random and you really can't find any fixed way to access the key you wish, you may try serialize the array using `json_encode` and then search the key-value pair using string method.

Comment: For something like this you're either going to have to visit every member as-stated, pre-compute some form of index [useful only if this is repetitive], or translate these structures into a format better suited for sorting/searching.